# Is there a relation between object size and locking performancein Java?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, size

In the famous Java Concurrency in Practice, section 2.4, it says that intrinsic locking approach, as against explicit locks was a bad design decision as its confusing and also "...it forces JVM implementors to make tradeoffs between object size and locking performance."
Can someone please explain how object size effects locking performance?

Comment: There should be no relationship to size with `synchronized` type locks (from my experience implementing this), and, from a brief review of the Java 5 locking scheme, I don't offhand see how there could be a dependency there either.  It does physically take more storage, of course, to implement the separate `Lock` objects, but that should be a fixed overhead.

Comment: @HotLicks thats what surprised me, size shudnt have any additional overhead, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since every object can be locked, this means that every object has to have enough place to store all the information we need when locking.

That's rather unappealing because the vast, vast majority of objects will never be locked so we're wasting lots of space. So in practice Hotspot solves this by using 2bits to record the state of the object and reusing the rest of the object header depending on these two bits.

Then there's the whole biased/non-biased locking stuff.. well you can start reading about it [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Synchronization). Hotspot documentation is not what I'd call extensive, but locking and object headers are better represented than most of the rest. But in doubt: Read the source code.

PS: We have a similar problem with the native hashcode of every object too. "Just use the memory address" isn't much good if your GC shuffles objects around. (But contrary to locking there's no real alternative - if we want this functionality)

Comment: thanks for the info, basically its about all primitive syncronization, irrespective of the size of the particular object used for locking

Comment: have you got some specifics to go with those statements? "lots" of space? what information is needed when locking?

Comment: @Toby Well at least the TID and a recursion counter. For details you'll have to look at the heavy lock classes in the hotspot source. Considering that this is added to every object even 1-2words are "lots of space" though.

Comment: @Toby Actually looked it up and the size of an ObjectMonitor object has about 16 variables all ints or intptrs. Why we need all that information? Well for that you'll have to read the code - rather complex class it is.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient locks use native word size e.g. 32-bit fields.  However you don't want to be adding 4 bytes to every object so instead AFAIK 1 bit is used, however setting this bit is more expensive that setting a word size.

Comment: Hmm can we do it without a CAS even if we use word sized fields? If not it's basically only read + bit shuffling + CAS vs. CAS - probably not that bad, but still slower.

Comment: @Voo not that bad in my experience as `synchronized` can be optimised by the JIT is ways Lock is not.

Comment: I'm talking about the synchronized implementation. Even if we used a wordsized locking header, we'd still need a CAS which should dominate the bit shuffling, so not much difference there. We're probably talking past each other though.

Comment: CAS is pretty fast, about 5 ns. An uncontested synchronized can be around 20 ns.

Comment: Sure but I claim the difference between bitshifting + CAS (as its done now) vs. CAS on a wordsized array would be basically just as fast so no real performance gain from doing that.

Comment: I agree that memory access cost is much higher than bit shifting.

Comment: The trick is to use a limited number of bits in the object header to indicate that there is an "object extension", and then place the (possibly swizzled) pointer to that extension in an area of the header that you first move to the extension.  The hard part is making this efficient, so not too much mainline code has to check for whether the object is extended or not.